# Only landscape view in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone

I want to create a iPhone Application. My aim is, it will be contains Landscape view only from loading time. How to disable portrait view from loading time?

Answer (score 1):

In your application plist file add a "Initial interface orientation" row and specify desired initial orientation there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is useful to rotate the menu controls only. It is not used to rotate the View control.

Comment: to rotate views you need to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in your viewcontrollers and return YES for landscape orientation from it

Comment: I used the above answers for my application.  and then i made some correction by using the following link...                               http://www.dejoware.com/blogpages/files/iphone_programming_statusbarless_landscapeonly_utility_app.php

Answer (score 0):

requires apple login

[Start my application in landscape mode?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/UserExperience/index.html)

IN your plist file

```
 <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

additional information

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1588.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the following answer.

### LandscapeViewController.h

```
#import < UIKit / UIKit.h >

@interface LandscapeViewController : UIViewController {

UIStatusBarStyle oldStatusBarStyle;

}

@end

----------------------------
LandscapeViewController.m
--------------------------


         #import "LandscapeViewController.h"


@implementation LandscapeViewController


        - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

      - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    oldStatusBarStyle = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarStyle];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];

}

       - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:oldStatusBarStyle animated:NO];    

}

      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

    NSLog(@"DDDDDDDDD");
}

      - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


      - (void)dealloc 
{

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

and refer the following link do that steps:

http://www.dejoware.com/blogpages/files/iphone_programming_statusbarless_landscapeonly_utility_app.php